# move installed flatpak applications

Tags: flatpak

In the flatpak documentation there are instructions for alternative locations to install the new applications.
But how do I move what is already installed to a new location? Simply moving what was in ~/.var/app/ did not have the expected effect

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems like Flatpak does store only generated data (like configs, cache and such) in `~/.var/app` and installs actual apps to system level by default. At least starting from some version. More in the docs: https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/using-flatpak.html (not that helpful though)